# Need help inserting item into Cosmos Collection

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have to insert an item into the collection. The code I have to GetProvider works but uses the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client class. I found some sample code on Microsoft's site to do the insert. It requires the use of the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos class. The code has one error, container is undefined.  So I added Container container and that clears that error but since there is no initializer, I now have the use of uninitialized object error. My application is a .NET Core 3.0 WEB API.

The code below is how I am implementing the insert. Is there a way to use just the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos library for an insert?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SchedulingAppointmentAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using ConnectionMode = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionMode;
using Database = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Database;
using PartitionKey = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PartitionKey;

public async void SaveAppointment(Appointments appointment)
        {
            try
            {
                using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey,
                      new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Https }))
                {
                    Database databasename = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseName });
                    DocumentCollection collectionname = await GetOrCreateCollectionAsync(DatabaseName, CollectionName);
                    Container container;// = await Database.CreateContainerAsync("container-id");
                    Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);

                    try
                    {
                        // Read the item to see if it exists.  
                        ItemResponse<Appointments> appointmentItemResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<Appointments>(appointment.id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(appointment.Provider_Id));
                    }

                    catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        // Create an item in the container representing the appointment. Note we provide the value of the partition key for this item, which is "ProviderID"
                        ItemResponse<Appointments> appointmentItemResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync<Appointments>(appointment, new PartitionKey(appointment.Provider_Id));

                    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't initialize `container` to anything, so this isn't going to work as written.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly pointed by @David , You are getting the null reference error as your container is uninitialized, you can use something like below :

We will need a database and a couple collections in our Cosmos DB.

```
var client = new CosmosClient(Endpoint, Authkey);
await client.Databases.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("DatabaseId", 400);
await client.Databases["DatabaseId"].Containers.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("ContainerA", "/partitionKey");
await client.Databases["DatabaseId"].Containers.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("ContainerB", "/partitionKey");
```

To get metadata on an existing database/collection we can do this:

```
await client.Databases["DatabaseId"].ReadAsync();
await client.Databases["DatabaseId"].Containers["ContainerA"].ReadAsync();
```

For creating entities, we would need :

```
var item = new SampleEntity
{
    Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Sample",
    PartitionKey = "a"
};
CosmosItemResponse<SampleEntity> res = await container.Items.CreateItemAsync(item.PartitionKey, item);
```

You can refer below repository for managing container :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ContainerManagement/Program.cs

Additional reference:

https://joonasw.net/view/exploring-cosmos-db-sdk-v3

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helped, please accept as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask.